# How to install superset on a macbook

Tags: python, apache-superset

I was confused when looking at the installation steps of superset on this page  http://superset.apache.org/installation.html

For the **OS Dependencies** part, the command for OSX is listed as "brew install pkg-config libffi openssl python". But my macbook does not have homebrew and I do not want to have one. I have installed pip though. And my python is installed via anaconda in Spyder. I am wondering is there any way to finish this OS dependencies job through pip method or in anaconda?

Next for the virtual environment. Is it necessary to install virtualenv to run superset? If not I would just ignore this step.

Due to my internet connection, my trials for downloading the "superset-0.20.4.tar.gz" file after typing "pip install superset" always failed. I will try at another place later but can someone tell me what would happen after this downloading? Do I just keep typing commands as the instruction says and it will just work out?

Comment: I suggest you learn about virtualenv and homebrew on mac is quite useful (not sure why you don't want to have it). If you want to go for a simpler solution you could try to use a docker image with superset. If you don't want to follow the standard installation instructions you need to know what you are doing otherwise you end up with something that doesn't work as intended

Comment: For homebrew it is mainly because I think have pip, conda and brew will be too much. If it's ok to have all three(like, it will not slow my computer), I would have one then. Same for the virtualenv, I am concerned with something like storage and processing speed. I have never used virtualenv before so I may not realize how useful it could be. I will connect to a better network and have those two then. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Brew will download stuff and install them like pip, it runs only when you call it, it won't run in the background slowind down your machine. Virtualenv is to have separated python environment in your machine (for example for project 1 you have 10 modules, but for project 2 you have only two, or different versions), it's just to keep things more clean. It's quite useful to know how to use virtual environments with Python, try to learn it

Comment: I'll surely learn it. Seems it would be pretty useful dealing with multiple projects. Thank you a lot!